# using concat with copy-of in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xsl code with the copy-of method , which copy the xml tag as it's
i want to concat the value with a single quote

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:foo="http://www.fo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of xml:id="id_94" select="concat('`',/TransmissionHeader ,'`')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is the input

```
<TransmissionHeader>hello</TransmissionHeader >
```

the output is

```
`hello`
```

but i want the output to be

```
`<TransmissionHeader>hello</TransmissionHeader>`
```

how to achieve that ?

Comment: What is your output method? If it's text, then why do you need the tags? If it's XML, then why do you need the quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected output can be produced using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy-of select="TransmissionHeader"/>
    <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, as I noted in a comment to your question, the result doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

That is an interesting use of <xsl:copy-of/>.
I would expect it to need a node() type input to work properly.
In your case you are saving "Hey, copy this string for me", due to the return type of a concat operation being a string. If you input a node() type value where a string is expected, it will always transform the given xpath into xpath/text() and just select the text inside it. (Just from experience, not 100% sure)

Your problem should be fixed by just writing:

```
<xsl:copy-of select=". | @*"/>
```

Copy-of makes a deep-copy, so every element within its structure will be copied. The normal <xsl:copy/> makes just a copy of the current element. Since the text inside your node is also viewed as a node() it will copy it too.

Comment: but i stil need to concat the xml tag with ` ` , and this one didn't solve it

Comment: i tried <xsl:copy-of select="concat('`',. | @*,'`')" it didn't work